# Capacitor ESR Calculation

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, feedback, esr

I'm trying to perform esr calculations of this capacitor(1uF):
https://alconelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/KP-6-JUNE-2019.pdf

to do that I need to know dissipation factor and at the bottom of the first page there is a dissipation factor-frequency graph, I'm going to use cap. at 60kHz and I choose dissipation factor as 10^-4 because the value is not clear.

When I calculated the "esr = dissipation factor / 2*pi*f*C"
esr=0.00026 Ohms in my situation which is too small in my opinion.

and when I calculate esr zero frequency: "1 / 2*pi*R*C"

fesrzero= more than 600MHz which look weird to me.

Am I doing the calculations right, I mean the values are unfamiliar to me and I'm not sure about it

source: https://forum.digikey.com/t/calculating-capacitor-esr-from-tan/2633

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the graph in the datasheet i see a dissibation factor value of approximately 2.5e-4 at 60kHz which leads to a ESR of 0.66m Ohms.

This is still less than the max. ESR of 5-8mOhms, but the typical value is not the same as the max value.